# Error with composer when I want to install friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, composer-php, symfony4

I want to install friendsofsymfony/elastica-bundle via composer, but I got an error with symfony/flex. I tried to update symfony/flex via composer but always the same error and also composer load from the cache the version v1.0.80 but I have in the file composer.json the version 1.4.2 . I tried to uninstall composer and install it again but it's working too.
Thank you for your help. This is the error I find:
[image]

Comment: can you show `composer --version`, I suspect your composer version is quite old. or the flex version is quite old. either way ... bring those two somehow in "sync", and you should be fine.

Comment: it appears the version of flex you're trying to install is ... quite old (May 2018), so I suppose your composer could be too recent. if you don't mind upgrading libraries, you could try `composer update` (maybe adapt composer.json before ... it's apparently out of sync with the composer.lock already) - github issue from ages ago: https://github.com/symfony/flex/issues/405

Comment: I thank you for your answer. the version of composer is:
Composer version 1.9.0 2019-08-02 20:55:32

Comment: with composer update I have this error:
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1610612736 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 67108864 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php on line 223
Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors